# Connect-busboy - Amazon S3 - Validation and return

Tags: express, amazon-s3, busboy

I am trying to directly upload files from the browser to Amazon S3 using connect-busboy with the following code (https://github.com/thaume/s3-streaming)

route - index.js:
        var awsUpload = require('../services/aws-streaming');

```
// Index route
// ===========
exports.index = function(req, res){
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    return awsUpload(req, function(err, url) {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(url));
    });
  }

  res.writeHead(200, { Connection: 'close' });
  res.end('<html><head></head><body>\
             <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">\
              <input type="file" name="filefield"><br />\
              <input type="submit">\
            </form>\
          </body></html>');
};
```

with my modified version of aws-streaming.js

```
// Initialize aws client
// =====================
var config = require('../config/' + 'development');
var Knox = require('knox');
var moment = require('moment');
var crypto = require('crypto');

// Create the knox client with your aws settings
Knox.aws = Knox.createClient({
  key: config.aws.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secret: config.aws.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  bucket: config.aws.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
  region: 'eu-west-1'
});

// S3 upload service - stream buffers to S3
// ========================================
var s3UploadService = function(req, next) {
  req.files = {};

  req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    if (!filename) {
      // If filename is not truthy it means there's no file
      return;
    }
    //////////////// CHECK FOR MIMETYE /////////////////////
    // If file is not "text/plain" - return //
    if (mimetype != "text/plain") {
      console.log('true!')
      return;  // A JSON array with an error "Wrong file type"!
    }
    // Create the initial array containing the stream's chunks
    file.fileRead = [];

    file.on('data', function(chunk) {
      // Push chunks into the fileRead array
      this.fileRead.push(chunk);
    });

    file.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Error while buffering the stream: ', err);
    });

    file.on('end', function() {
      // Concat the chunks into a Buffer
      var finalBuffer = Buffer.concat(this.fileRead);

      req.files[fieldname] = {
        buffer: finalBuffer,
        size: finalBuffer.length,
        filename: filename,
        mimetype: mimetype
      };

      // Generate date based folder prefix
      var datePrefix = moment().format('YYYY[/]MM');
      var key = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
      var hashFilename = key + '-' + filename;

      var pathToArtwork = '/artworks/' + datePrefix + '/' + hashFilename;

      var headers = {
        'Content-Length': req.files[fieldname].size,
        'Content-Type': req.files[fieldname].mimetype,
        'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
      };

      Knox.aws.putBuffer( req.files[fieldname].buffer, pathToArtwork, headers, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
          console.error('error streaming image: ', new Date(), err);
          return next(err);
        }
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
          console.error('error streaming image: ', new Date(), err);
          return next(err);
        }
        console.log('Amazon response statusCode: ', response.statusCode);
        console.log('Your file was uploaded');
        next();
      });
    });
  });

  req.busboy.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('Error while parsing the form: ', err);
    next(err);
  });

  req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Done parsing the form!');
    // When everythin's done, render the view
    next(null, 'http://www.google.com');
  });

  // Start the parsing
  req.pipe(req.busboy);
};

module.exports = s3UploadService;
```

What I would like to do is to validate the mimetype and return a json array with the error message, ending the parsing of the form and not upload the file. Have added code to aws-streaming, but it will not return even if validates to true. What have I done wrong?

Also the code runs the callback when it is finished parsing the form, but I would like it to be run when the file is actually uploaded. How can I achieve this, comment out the next() in 'finish' event and move it to the Knox.aws.putBuffer?

Im using Express 4

Comment: `if (mimetype != "text/plain") {
      console.log('true!');
      file.resume();
      return res.status(400).json({status: "wrong mime});  // A JSON array with an error "Wrong file type"!
    }` . See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465882/node-busboy-abort-upload)